# Soap array elements need namespace

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl, delphi-7

The Delphi 7 client does not include the namespace on the array elements. The web service fails to deserialize the array when the namespace is not included.

Using Delphi 7 with the SOAP/WSDL update 24535.

can I can do it by accessing array elements ?